# How does one scroll down using the trackpad in the new achievements view?

Tags: support, top-bar

So, first off, I *love* the new achievements view! It gives me exactly the sort of information I want to know, and showing it first on meta is exactly the right way to beta test :)

Now, the achievements seem to cut off yesterday at an indeterminate point. Note that one bit of activity is from yesterday on SciFi.  The question I have is this - Is this just because I really reached the end of activity that is being captured, or would there have been more, if there was some sort of scroll that I was unable to activate?

In clicking around, I noticed that "Earlier this week" appeared when collapsing 'Yesterday' leading me to suspect that more activity would be available, if only I could scroll.

Is this just an omission?

And, is there anyway to get this same information as a page I could simply bookmark?

[image]

---

For reproduction:

- I am on a MAC OS 10.8.5
- Chrome Version 30.0.1599.101

Update:

I am using a trackpad on my MacBook Pro - not a magic mouse with the scrolling functionality.  If I use a magic mouse, I am able to get the scrollbars to appear, but when I just use my trackpad, I am not able to get scrollbars - in this window only.

Comment: I have scrollbars on that, seems to be a bug

Comment: Is that...Safari on Mac OS X? In that case, [just scroll](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204698/cant-scroll-horizontally-in-code-block#comment654729_204698).

Comment: This is Chrome on a Mac, and I tried that :)  I also tried moving the mouse to where I would expect a scroll bar - no joy.

Comment: Ah, well, still [meta-tag:status-norepro] here. I'm able to use scroll  gestures inside of the popup if my mouse is over it.

Comment: Status-norepro here as well.

Answer (score 4):

Ultimately, this is an issue not with the top-bar, but rather with the gestures of the trackpad.

To scroll using the trackpad, [you need to use a double-fingered scroll](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4721) on the trackpad.